# Linkedin Preview Scraper Agent is blocked on WAF

Tags: linkedin-api, web-application-firewall

If someone wants to share a page/link from our public website on Linkedin, the preview doesn't get rendered properly. Also if we check the Post Inspector (https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector) it ends in a error.

We have figured out, that Linkedin is calling the URL with a specific agent with some strange HTTP-Headers. Our WAF is blocking this headers, this makes scraping the preview impossible.

Of course we can add these headers to the whitelist, but as soon Linkedin rename and/or add some other headers we have the same problem again.

Is there a good developer documentation about Linkedin's agents? Or does anyone has a good (and safe) idea how to passthrough Linkedin's agents?